# dialogflow, Google Sign-In for the Assistant (include Google Home)

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-signin, actions-on-google, google-home

I am developing an Action that needs to catch the name/email of the user after they consent.

I found an interesting tutorial (https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/how-to-use-google-sign-in-for-the-assistant-b818f3de9211).
clientID is a "copy-paste" of clientID existing in Google Action Account Linking.
The intent is invoked successfully!

```
const app = dialogflow({
  clientId: 'my_client_id_from_google_action_ACCOUNT_LINKING.apps.googleusercontent.com'
});

app.intent("Hours", conv => {
  console.log('--- ok');
  const payload = conv.user.profile.payload;

  if (payload) {
    const name = payload.name;
    const email = payload.email;
    console.log('--- name: ' + name);
    console.log('--- email: ' + email);
  } else {
    conv.ask("Not signed in yet.");
    conv.ask(new Suggestion("want to sign in"));
  }
});
```

}
});

Actually, I am not able to get the user's email/name.

I would like to get the name and email address.

---

I do really appreciate your help!
Neither Payload nor conv.user.profile.token are populated.
I am newbie in this programming language and concept, and will put the entire code. Thank you so much for your time and patience.

Entire code index.js:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {dialogflow,SignIn} = require("actions-on-google");

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*';

const app = dialogflow({
    clientId: '------------------sas6.apps.googleusercontent.com',
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
    console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
    console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

    function fallback(agent) {
        agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    }

    function welcome(agent) {
        app.intent("Get Sign-In", conv => {
            agent.add('--- ok Get Sign-In');
            console.log('--- ok Get Sign-In');
            const payload = conv.user.profile.payload;

            if (payload) {
                console.log('--- payload if');
                console.log('--- name: ' + payload.name);
                console.log('--- email: ' + payload.email);
            } else {
                console.log('--- payload else');
                conv.ask("Not signed in yet.");
                conv.ask(new Suggestion("want to sign in"));
            }
        });
    }

    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
    intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "my first agent",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "semistandard --fix \"**/*.js\"",
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-functions": "2.0.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "actions-on-google": "2.2.0", 
    "googleapis": "^27.0.0",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "0.5.0",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say you're not able to get it, what is happening? Can you update your question with an explanation of what is happening and what your setting is in the Account Linking section of the Action console.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Will try "with my (newbie) words". So I check the box "sign-in required" in google "actions integrations form", and when I test it (simulator), the app ask me (user) for authorization, etc.. I accept, and receive an email notifying me for the app account creation. In the 2nd access of the app, no more sign-in because account is already create. But now I would get the name and email of the created account. The code above does not work, I am not able to get payload.name in order to write: agent.add(`--- name: ` + conv.user.profile.payload.name); Thank you. Carlos.

Comment: Is `payload` populated at all? If so, with what? If not, is `conv.user.profile.token` populated?

Comment: Dear Prisoner, I do really appreciate your help. I edited the post with the entire index.js and package.json. The intents "Default Welcome Intent" is create and "enable webhook call for this intent" is active. So the intent is invoked, but no name, no email from user. Thank you again for your patience. Carlos

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code that point to the fundamental problem. Let's look at each one.

**Fundamental problem: You never ask the user to log in**

While you have code that appears to handle the response from a sign-in request, there doesn't seem to be any code that asks the user to sign in.

While there are other ways that the user can login (they could sign in on your website, for example), the typical way is to prompt them to do so using the Signin helper in the response to one of your Intents. It might look something like this

```
app.intent('Start Signin', conv => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'))
})
```

if you're using the actions-on-google library. Which actually leads to a different problem.

**You're mixing the dialogflow-fulfillment and actions-on-google library**

And, worse, you're doing it in a way that is probably causing problems.

It looks like you are primarily using the dialogflow-fulfillment library, since this is what is setup in the Firebase Function handler and what triggers the call to `agent.handleRequest(intentMap);`.

Although you setup a different handler with the call `app.intent()`, you do this inside your welcome intent (judging by its name), which you generally don't want to do. There is also nothing that is setup to call this handler. Typically you'd set this up with a line such as

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Since this line is so much like the dialogflow-fulfillment one, it drives home the point that you should do fulfillment with one library or the other - not both. In general, if you're doing Actions on Google stuff, stick to the actions-on-google library.